# What does it mean when in-app purchases are "in review" while the app binary itself is still "waiting for review"?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am a bit confused by this. How is Apple supposed to review in app purchase content without the app? All my IAPs are "in review" while the app itself is "waiting for review" since two days.

This is not too programming related BUT it might save other developers time to know this can happen and why. What I did:

1) Updloaded IAP content packages so I can test it.

2) Assigned IAP content packages to app, then submitted app via Xcode.

3) Found bug and rejected binary.

4) Fixed bug, resubmitted binary. But this time no way to assign the IAPs to app. They were already "waiting for review".

Did my app get stuck in a deadlock situation? Did anyone else ever experience this?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the In App Purchases will be reviewed once your app goes into review. Your In App Purchases are already associated with the app, are they not?

However I would recommend you contact Apple through iTunes connect. I've always had good success with this in the past.

Select the 'Contact Us' link at the bottom of the iTunes connect page. In the form that appears, select App Review and Check Review Status, and then select the 'contact us' link in the text that appears.

[image]

Then describe your issue in the form, and they should tell you what you need to do.

Comment: Yes, I associated the IAPs with the app previously, before I had to self-reject the binary to fix a bug. Thanks for Contact Us tip.

Comment: Hello @openfrog ,I am also stuck at this situation. What did you do to resolve this issue ? thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to fix this (its not ideal):

1. Delete in app purchase that is "waiting for review" in iTunes connect.
2. Recreate in app purchase with a different product id (you can just add a number to the end).
3. Refractor old references in your purchase code to the new id.
4. Rebuild, re-associate the product, and re-upload!